# Cannot instantiate abstract class?

Tags: c++, class, abstract, instantiation

I got this:

```
class Core
{
protected:
    static unsigned int id_seed;
    unsigned int id;
    std::string status;

public:
    friend class CPU;
    Core();
    ~Core();

    virtual void procesare(std::string aplicatie) = 0;
};


class CoreScreen: public Core
{
public:
    CoreScreen();
    ~CoreScreen();

    void procesare(std::string aplicatie);
};
```

and corescreen.cpp:

```
#include "CoreScreen.h"

CoreScreen::CoreScreen()
{
}

CoreScreen::~CoreScreen()
{
}

void CoreScreen::procesare(std::string aplicatie)
{
    std::string buffer;
    std::ifstream file_in(aplicatie);
    if (file_in.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Aplicatia " << aplicatie << " ruleaza: " << std::endl;
        while (getline(file_in, buffer)) {
            std::cout << buffer;
        }
        file_in.close();
    }
    else {
        throw new CExceptie(APP_FAIL, " Aplicatia nu a putut rula!");
    }
}
```

When I use in main:

```
CoreScreen CS1, CS2, CS3, CS4;
```

I get this error: 'Core' cannot instantiate abstract class.

What's the problem? I thought I have my virtual function declared in CoreScreen correctly.

Comment: You've declared it as pure virtual. I'm surprised you're even *allowed* to implement it. Take off the `= 0` in the declaration.

Comment: @Gabriel Stoica - have you resolved the problem?  The code you posted looks OK, including `void procesare()`. I believe the problem is "somewhere else".  Q: Are you using a "Core" directly anywhere?  Q: Could you post the exact line that's giving the error?

Answer (score 0):

As I presume you know, "Core" is an [abstract class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-virtual-functions-and-abstract-classes/), by virtue of the fact it has a [pure virtual function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-virtual-functions-and-abstract-classes/): `virtual void procesare(std::string aplicatie) = 0;`.

I presume you also know that you can't instantiate an abstract class: hence your error.

The question is:

Why does the compiler think you're trying to instantiate an instance of "Core"?

Are you?

It *looks* like you're trying to instantiate four CoreScreen objects: `CoreScreen CS1, CS2, CS3, CS4;`.  If so, that should be perfectly OK.

You're correct: `procesare()` is virtual ("pure virtual", as it happens).  You've indeed overridden it correctly in CoreScreen.cpp: it *DOESN'T* look like that's the problem.

Q: Did you ever implement `Core::Core()` and `Core::~Core()` anywhere?  If not, how did you even compile?

Q: Are you *SURE* you're not trying to create an instance of "Core" anywhere (even "accidentally")?

For whatever it's worth, the following [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) compiles and runs fine (Ubuntu 18, GCC 7.3.0):

TestCore.h:

```
/*
 * TestCore.h
 */
#ifndef TESTCORE_H_
#define TESTCORE_H_

#include <string>

class Core
{
protected:
    static unsigned int id_seed;
    unsigned int id;
    std::string status;

public:
    friend class CPU;
    Core();
    ~Core();

    virtual void procesare(std::string aplicatie) = 0;
};


class CoreScreen: public Core
{
public:
    CoreScreen();
    ~CoreScreen();

    void procesare(std::string aplicatie);
};
#endif /* TESTCORE_H_ */
```

TestCore.cpp:

```
/*
 * TestCore.cpp
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "TestCore.h"

Core::Core()
{
    std::cout << "Core::Core()..." << std::endl;
}

Core::~Core()
{
    std::cout << "Core::~Core()..." << std::endl;
}

CoreScreen::CoreScreen()
{
    std::cout << "CoreScreen::CoreScreen()..." << std::endl;
}

CoreScreen::~CoreScreen()
{
    std::cout << "CoreScreen::~CoreScreen()..." << std::endl;
}

void CoreScreen::procesare(std::string aplicatie)
{
    std::cout << "CoreScreen::procesare(" << aplicatie << ")"  << std::endl;;
}

int main () {
    std::cout << ">>main()..." << std::endl;
    CoreScreen CS1, CS2, CS3, CS4;
    CS1.procesare("Testing CS1");
    std::cout << "<<main()." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
>>main()...
Core::Core()...
CoreScreen::CoreScreen()...
Core::Core()...
CoreScreen::CoreScreen()...
Core::Core()...
CoreScreen::CoreScreen()...
Core::Core()...
CoreScreen::CoreScreen()...
CoreScreen::procesare(Testing CS1)
<<main().
```

You'll note that I implemented Core::Core() and Core::~Core().  If you don't need them - then don't even put them in your .h class definition.

'Hope that helps

Comment: shouldnt u initialize id_seed also? surprised it links.

Comment: "All static data is initialized to zero when the first object is created, if no other initialization is present."